# Windows Media Player Styled ListView

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, custom-controls

Hi I'm working on a project and I'd like to have large image displayed on the left and a regular list on the left, akin to Windows Media Player's ListView in Album mode. (see image below)

[image: Windows Media Player ListView]

Does anyone know of where I can get a control that does this in VB.NET/C# in WinForms?

Comment: The concept of styled listview implies WPF ;)

Comment: @Alex: Sorry about that editing war we just had going. :-) Your image wasn't showing up on my computer and sometimes embedded links to ImageShack don't work out properly. It just so happened that we were both editing tags at the same time.

Comment: @Cody: No problem here. The image wasn't showing up on mine either. Plus I often tag C# and VB.NET in order to get the attention of developers of both languages. I guess I'll follow your edit and use the .net tag from now on.

Comment: @Alex: I think VB.NET and C# tags probably imply more of a language focus, whereas this more of a design question involving WinForms. It's pretty much language-agnostic. Plus there are a limited number of tags. :-) Otherwise, I agree with you, and I might otherwise have left both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be *extremely* difficult to implement entirely by yourself in WinForms. As commenters have pointed out, this is a task perfectly suited for WPF, but presumably that's not an option in your case.

Therefore, **I strongly recommend that you investigate the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) control.** Here, most of the design and infrastructure have already been implemented for you, and all you'll have to do is tweak it to look like the Windows Media Player example.

As the linked page explains, several aspects of the ObjectListView are slightly different from the standard ListView control. The author claims it's better and more intuitive, but I honestly never have taken the time to make the switch (I'm not much on custom theming though, so there's been less need). Either way, it's important to note that it's "not a drop-in replacement". If your project isn't too far under development, I think you'll find this is definitely the way to go.

Plus, it's free and the source code is available. That makes it a big winner in my book.

Just for fun, here's a sample of what you can do in ObjectListView with relative ease:
[image: ObjectListView sample]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this in WinForms as it is pretty restrictive [Unless you embed a WPF control in WinForms, which pretty much invalidates the objective of using WinForms altogether IMHO]... you could use a listbox with a datatemplate and a couple of bindings and it will work, but if you really need it to be a Grid-Like thing you should dig into the DataGrid:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.95%29.aspx#

Take in account the DataGrid is a .NET4/WPF CodePlex Pack-only Control :)